# Countifs with multiple criteria in one column and single criteria in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Column A :   A  A  B  B  C  D  E  F  A       Column B :  Y  N  Y  Y  Y  N  Y  N  Y

Count with criteria A and B in "Column A"  with criteria Y in "Column B.

I tried with this fomula :
COUNTIFS(A2:A10,"A",B2:B10,"Y")+COUNTIFS(A2:A10,"B",B2:B10,"Y")

Please suggest simplified formula.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SUMPRODUCT Formula to get the desired result. If your data is in A1:A9 & B1:B9 put this Array Formula in C1.

First put the formula without Braces and then from within the Formula Bar press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to get the array formula.

Once array formula is in place and you exit the cell, do not click in the formula bar on that cell again, else the array shall be lost.

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(IF(A1:A9="A",IF(B1:B9="Y",1,0),0)*1)+SUMPRODUCT(IF(A1:A9="B",IF(B1:B9="Y",1,0),0)*1)}
```

[image]